# Troubleshooting why apps get stuck 'exiting' on MacOS Sierra (ps state flag ?E)

Tags: macos, troubleshooting

On my MBP running MacOS Sierra, I have apps getting stuck while "exiting" (State flag E), which means they no longer show up in the UI, nor in the Activity Monitor, but they remain visible using 'ps'

Here's a sample output ('ps auxw | grep "?E"'):

```
USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
root             11359   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  ?E   11:40PM   0:00.00 (Python)
MYUSERNAME       10190   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  ?E   11:40PM   0:00.00 (AOSHeartbeat)
root             10150   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  ?Es  11:40PM   0:00.00 (fontworker)
MYUSERNAME        7483   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  ?E   11:38PM   0:00.00 (GoogleSoftwareUp)
```

There's no way to get these out but by rebooting, and since they're stuck, it cannot reboot gracefully, so I have to force powerdown... Sometimes I can work for days, sometimes I have to powerdown 4-5 times a day...
Once an app is ?E, I cannot restart it either, so it definitely is still a locked process for MacOS, even though it isn't visible anywhere else.

Sometimes the behavior is accompanied by the ever descriptive “The application ‘Application.app’ is not open anymore” error.

Can anyone give pointers/hints/ideas on how to troubleshoot this and figure out what is causing this, so I can attempt to fix it?

(Because all major search-engines filter out characters like '?', I cannot find anything useful there either!)

Comment: Splitting hairs: these processes are probably not *running* (unless you see them using CPU time in ``ps``), but just *non-terminated* processes (so they can still have files open, and therefore they can hold locks). I don’t know any way to get rid of them, although it may help if you can figure out why they’re not dying properly. Do you have any tools like `lsof`?

Comment: Dang! never thought of trying lsof... I will try that as soon as I see ?E processes again!

(PS: I replaced 'running' with 'locked' to remove any doubt about the status of said processes, because I too am very certain they're not actually running anymore)

Comment: (1) Any progress?  (You can post an answer to your own question, and, if it’s good enough, you may earn some reputation points from it.) (2) See also [kill -9 hangs, unable to kill process (murder-proof process)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55195/23408) and [What if ‘kill -9’ does not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/23408)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went away after a round of updates, but there were many things updated at the same time, so I still don't know what caused it. I was never able to find a common cause.